# javascript for loop not working in xslt

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am using the below javascript code in XSLT style sheet.It's working without for loop. But i got the error illegal syntax error near "<". Please help me to do this.

```
function activate(id)
      {
      try
      {
      alert('enter');
      var table = document.getElementById('billmain');
      var valueImp="";
      alert(table.rows.length)

      for(i=1; i <table.rows.length; i++)
      {
      valueImp = table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
      alert(valueImp);
      }
      return false;
      }catch(ex)
      {
      alert(ex.Message);

      }
      }
```

Comment: Or at least post the markup

Answer (score 2):

Well an XSLT stylesheet is an XML document so XML syntax rules apply meaning you need to escape the `<` less-than sign as `&lt;` or use a CDATA section e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
      <script><![CDATA[
function activate(id)
      {
      try
      {
      alert('enter');
      var table = document.getElementById('billmain');
      var valueImp="";
      alert(table.rows.length)

      for(i=1; i <table.rows.length; i++)
      {
      valueImp = table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
      alert(valueImp);
      }
      return false;
      }catch(ex)
      {
      alert(ex.Message);

      }
      }
]]></script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- further templates go here -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```